# Did Professor Trelawney sense that a part of Voldemort resides in Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, sybill-trelawney

In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, during a lecture in Divination where Harry suddenly dozed off, Professor Trelawney said to him:

> “I was saying, my dear, that you were clearly born under the
>   baleful influence of Saturn,” said Professor Trelawney, a faint note of resentment in her voice at the fact that he had obviously not
>   been hanging on her words.
>
> “Born under — what, sorry?” said Harry.
>
> “Saturn, dear, the planet Saturn!” said Professor Trelawney,
>   sounding definitely irritated that he wasn’t riveted by this news. “I
>   was saying that Saturn was surely in a position of power in the
>   heavens at the moment of your birth. . . . **Your dark hair** . . . **your
>   mean stature** . . . **tragic losses so young in life** . . . I think I am right
>   in saying, my dear, **that you were born in midwinter**?”
>
> “No,” said Harry, “I was born in July.”

As we all know, a part of Voldemort's soul still resides in Harry during this time. And also, Voldemort was born in midwinter.

Was she maybe talking about Voldemort here? Or just one of her other predictions that does not end up being true?

Comment: It's possible. Voldemort was born on 31st December.

Comment: I always got tripped up by this quote. As an Australian, July *is* midwinter

Answer (score 1):

I don't think she knew that a part Voldemort resided inside Harry. Dumbledore said in *Order of the Phoenix* (I think) that he gave a teaching position to Professor Trelawney only so that he can keep her safe after she had made the prophecy, as on interviewing her for the job she didn't perform well and he found that she didn't have any skills of her ancestor until she made the prophecy. Trelawney doesn't even know that she had made a prophecy that had such a critical impact on the wizarding and human world.

Comment: Can your provide sources for the things you've stated?

Comment: Of course but I dont have the book now but i got this after googling

"Sixteen years ago, Dumbledore interviewed Sybill Trelawney for the Divination position, meeting her at a pub in Hogsmeade. Although she was descended from a gifted Seer, she herself seemed minimally talented and Dumbledore declined her the post. As he was about to leave, Trelawney fell into a trance."

Here is the link https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles%27_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Books/Order_of_the_Phoenix/Chapter_37

Comment: You can read the book again to make it sure. I wont lie about dumbledore... :P

Comment: I haven't read the book, so I wouldn't really know where to look, neither am I very keen (if I have this question) to go read a book that's over 200,000 words. I'm not saying you need to edit in now, but sources would help your answer :)

Comment: trust me u r saying that because u haven't read the book. And also this question will only intrigue the ones who have actually read the book (no offence) so they would love to go back to read it again... :)

Comment: Look I'm not trying to tell you what to do, I'm just providing advice to a new user from someone who's spent a lot of time on the site, what type of answers the site likes to see.

Comment: Part of the deal with Trelawney though is that her predictions [aren't as bad as the reader is led to believe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124533/64888). Rowling uses her seemingly hopeless veneer to foreshadow actual future plot points.