# Can Muggles learn to do some forms of divination as taught in Prof. Trelawney's class?

Tags: harry-potter, divination

Profesor Trelawney's classes do not seem to involve magic spells or wands, at least in those classes shown to the readers. I don't remember her mentioning anywhere needing to know about spell or wand work, to succeed in her class.

She does say that a true seer needs to have the "inner eye", what ever that is, and the true predictions that she does make regarding Harry and Voldemort seem to be things even other wizards might not have been able to do.

However, we are shown that her class also involves reading tea leaves for divination, which just seems to be some form of pattern recognition.

In fact, Firenze's class also mostly seems to involve observing stars, recognizing patterns and knowing what certain patterns mean, rather then involving actual spells and magic.

Would muggles be able to learn and perform some of these divination methods? Would a muggle be able to make an AI pattern recognition software to scan the pattern in tea leaves and predict the future using a computer?

Comment: I'd say no, the techniques wouldn't work for muggles, because they don't work for witches and wizards either.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124533/77809

Comment: The tea leaves might work for me. But I'd hate to see my tea leaves predicting my death . . . (FYI, I am a Muggle, and have confirmed that I am).

Comment: @WiggotheWookie The striking thing about Trelawny's *correct* predictions is that they don't arise from any of the methods she teaches.  She makes wild predictions randomly in conversation, and sometimes they come true.  And her trance-predictions come true.  This makes it seem like divination is not something that can actually be taught, like brewing a potion.